# Why did the old questions get more upvotes?

Tags: discussion, voting, questions

Looking at the [archives](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions?page=92&sort=newest) I just noticed that the early questions got much more upvotes than the [newer](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions?page=10&sort=newest). Why?

I understand that the old questions had more time to get votes and that the majority of the users were very enthusiastic about WPSE. But still …
Are new users made aware enough for the importance of votes on questions? If not, how could we improve the system?

Or do I overestimate this detail?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Some of this is natural.

In the private beta, everyone can vote. In the early public beta, you have mostly experienced users, many of which will have the +100 reputation bonus for having a +200 account in the network.

However, as new users enter, many of them won't have the [15 minimum rep required to upvote](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/faq#reputation). The voting buttons are quite prominent by design so hopefully new users are figuring this out.

We did add the voters tab on the users page to make this more visible and to give a "voting leaderboard" of sorts.

https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/users?tab=voters

And of course we always encourage you to encourage your fellow new community members to vote...

http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/10/vote-early-vote-often/

Comment: Oh, I didn’t know about the reputation limit. I see now that webapps.stackexchange.com shows a similar pattern, while writers.stackexchange.com seems to be still in the vote-up-when-you-can phase. Or they are just [more aware](http://meta.writers.stackexchange.com/questions/36/not-much-voting-going-on) of the topic.

Comment: OMG! ... i'm the most active voter... :-o ...when did that happen. Come on people, get voting!..